# Why arguments of std::binary_search are forward iterators?

Tags: c++

While perusing http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search I've noticed it takes forward iterator as an argument. Now I'm confused, since I thought it would rather be an random access iterator, so the binary search will be actually binary.

To satisfy my curiosity, I've written a little program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <forward_list>
#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uintdistr(-4000000, 4000000);
    std::mt19937 twister(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()));
    size_t arr[] = { 200000, 400000, 800000, 1600000, 3200000, 6400000, 12800000 };
    for(auto size : arr)
    {
        std::list<int> my_list;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            my_list.push_front(uintdistr(twister));
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock> start, end;
        my_list.sort(); //fixed
        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        std::binary_search(my_list.begin(), my_list.end(), 1252525);

        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        long long unsigned elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start).count();
        std::cout << "Test finished in " << elapsed_time << "\n";
    }
}
```

Compiling it with gcc 4.7.0 and running

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

provides following results on my machine:

```
Test finished in 0
Test finished in 15625
Test finished in 15625
Test finished in 46875
Test finished in 93750
Test finished in 171875
Test finished in 312500
```

So it looks like it doesn't actually do a binary search on a forward list.
Now my questions are:

Why such a confusing name?

Why does the code like this allowed?

Why does the reference says it's "Logarithmic in the distance between first and last"?

What does the standard has to say about it?

EDIT: Now the code sorts the list before search - stupid mistake, now the results are:

```
Test finished in 46875
Test finished in 109375
Test finished in 265625
Test finished in 546875
Test finished in 1156250
Test finished in 2625000
Test finished in 6375000
```

And of course still not logarithmic ;)

Comment: Doesn't the list have to be sorted for binary_search to work?

Comment: @J99 Good point. I will soon update my question.

Comment: It still only needs to do log(n) comparisons with forward iterators (and random access). The advantage of random access is the ability to jump forward rather than seeking forward.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The docs of the original SGI STL implementation, from which the standard was derived, [states that](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/binary_search.html)

> The number of comparisons is logarithmic: at most log(last - first) + 2. If `ForwardIterator` is a Random Access Iterator then the number of steps through the range is also logarithmic; otherwise, the number of steps is proportional to last - first.

That is, the number of *comparisons* is always logarithmic, while the number of advancements, which are affected by the lack of random-accessibility, can be linear. In practice, [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) is probably used, for which the complexity is constant if the iterator is random access, linear otherwise.

A binary search with a linear number of iterator advancements, but with a logarithmic number of comparisons makes sense if a comparison is very expensive. If, for example, you have a sorted linked-list of complicated objects, which require disk- or network-access to compare, you're probably much better off with a binary search than with a linear one.

Comment: But there will be twice more iterations than linear search. The comparisons would have to be very expensive for this to be faster, won't it?

Comment: That's true, but since advancing an iterator is usually very cheap, it's easy to beat it. For example, if your comparison sends you to read a file, binary search will easily beat linear search.

Comment: Yeah, now that makes sense - surely dereferencing a pointer is far more quicker than accessing hard drive or network. So binary search may be useful in this type of situation. I've learned something new. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Contrary to what [websites may say](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) (e.g. "logarithmic in `distance(first, last)`"), the standard actually only speaks about the *comparisons* (e.g. 25.4.3.1, `lower_bound`):

> Complexity: At most `log2(last − first) + O(1)` comparisons

The incrementing of the iterator is *not* included in the complexity! Note though that the standard library requires all iterator increments to have amortized constant complexity, so there'll be a cost of order O(N) coming from incrementing the iterators (but presumably this has a very small leading factor). In parti­cu­lar (25.4.3):

> For non-random access iterators [the algorithms] execute a linear number of steps.

Answer (score 2):

The standard specifies the sorted search algorithms (`std::lower_bound()`, `std::upper_bound()`, and `std::binary_search()`) to work in linear time for forward and binary iterators. For random access the time is logarithmic.

Note that the number of `comparisons` is restricted to be logarithmic, however.